# Asp net AJAX in a MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I tryed to use some AJAX in my MasterPage file, but got this error :

> http://localhost:15354/website/MasterPage.master/Login Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

I red on some forums that we can't call a function with AJAX from a MasterPage like this :

```
function Login() {
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.user = "";
        obj.pass = "";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MasterPage.master/Login",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my function in the code behind :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Login(string user, string pass)
{


    return "";
}
```

How do I do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to have webservice for this and call the webservice url from ajax request.

---

```
$.ajax({
    /// <summary>
    ///  Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request
    /// </summary>
    type: "POST",
    url: "AjaxServer.asmx/Login",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        /// <summary>
        /// when success
        /// </summary>
        alert(response.d);
    },
    failure: function(msg) {
        /// <summary>
        /// when there is an error
        /// </summary>
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});​
```

Comment: I created a WebService.asmx, now im gettin 'Unknown web method Login. Parameter name methodName'

Comment: Success! I had to remove "static" from my method in the asmx file

Comment: Can you edit your answer and remove the url: "/Login" because it doens't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can create .ascx for login information and call ajax there

Answer (score 2):

master pages have no life of there own
master page methods invoke in all pages that inherits master
so you can call your method from any page that uses master page

$.ajax({
  url: 'Login.aspx/Login',
  type: 'POST',...

Answer (score 1):

Move the server side code to a helper page, ie webmethods.aspx and call it there instead.